# Installing Net::Pcap using strawberry perl on windows 10

Tags: perl, libpcap, winpcap, strawberry-perl, npcap

I am trying to install Net::Pcap (https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Pcap) using edition of portable strawberry Perl v5.28.1 ,below are my steps :

1.I installed npcap (winpcap for windows 10 ) from https://nmap.org/npcap/#download

2.I downloaded the npcap sdk from https://nmap.org/npcap/#download

3.I extracted the SDK zip folders  to c:/WdpPack and verifies Include and Lib folders includes the header files and libraries

4.Then run the following command

```
perl Makefile.PL INC=-IC:/WpdPack/Include "LIBS=-LC:/WpdPack/Lib -lwpcap"
```

i get the below error message :

```
socket.h patched... ok
looking for -lwpcap... yes
checking for pcap_lib_version() in -lwpcap... no
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
You appear to lack the WinPcap developer pack.

If it is installed in a non-standard location, please try setting the LIBS
and INC values on the command line.  For instance, if you have unzipped the
developer's pack in C:\WpdPack, you should execute:

    perl Makefile.PL INC=-IC:/WpdPack/Include "LIBS=-LC:/WpdPack/Lib -lwpcap"

Or get and install the WinPcap developer's pack from
  http://www.winpcap.org/install/
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I enabled the `$DEBUG` flag in `Makefile.PL` and from the output it seems like the compiler cannot find the header `pcap.h`.  It is strange since the compiler is given the  `-IC:/WpdPack/Include` flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to compile this by moving the SDK folders from `C:\WdpPack` to my `C:\User` folder. I am not so familiar with Windows, so I am not sure why this works, maybe something to do with permissions?

**Update**:

After running `perl Makefile.PL`, running `gmake` to compile the module fails with errors:

```
[...]
stubs.inc:91:8: error: redefinition of 'struct pcap_if'
[...]
stubs.inc:267:5: error: conflicting types for 'pcap_compile_nopcap'
[...]
stubs.inc:357:8: error: redefinition of 'struct pcap_rmtauth'
[...]
stubs.inc:363:10: error: conflicting types for 'pcap_open'
[...]
stubs.inc:438:8: error: redefinition of 'struct pcap_send_queue'
[...]
stubs.inc:497:8: error: redefinition of 'struct pcap_samp'
```

To fix this, edit the file `stubs.inc`:

- delete lines 91-97

  ```
  struct pcap_if {
      struct pcap_if *next;
      char *name;     /* name to hand to "pcap_open_live()" */
      char *description;  /* textual description of interface, or NULL */
      struct pcap_addr *addresses;
      bpf_u_int32 flags;  /* PCAP_IF_ interface flags */
  };
  ```
- delete lines : 267-271

  ```
  int pcap_compile_nopcap(int snaplen, int linktype, struct bpf_program *fp, char *str, int optimize, bpf_u_int32 netmask);
  int pcap_compile_nopcap(int snaplen, int linktype, struct bpf_program *fp, char *str, int optimize, bpf_u_int32 netmask) {
      FUNCTION_NOT_IMPLEMENTED_ERROR(pcap_compile_nopcap)
      return -1;
  ```
- delete lines: 357-361

  ```
  struct pcap_rmtauth {
      int type;
      char *username;
      char *password;
  };
  ```
- delete lines lines 438-442:

  ```
  struct pcap_send_queue{
      u_int maxlen;
      u_int len;
      char *buffer;
  };
  ```
- delete lines 519-521:

  ```
  struct pcap_samp {
     int method;
     int value;
  };
  ```

Now `gmake` compiles the files, but the linker fails:

```
[...]
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Pcap.o:Pcap.c:(.text+0x23be): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Pcap.o:Pcap.c:(.text+0x2580): undefined reference to `pcap_geterr'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Pcap.o:Pcap.c:(.text+0x2590): undefined reference to `pcap_stats'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Pcap.o:Pcap.c:(.text+0x2820): undefined reference to `pcap_fileno'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Pcap.o:Pcap.c:(.text+0x29c4): undefined reference to `pcap_file'

[...]
```

The problem here was that we linked with the 32-bit library `wpcap.lib`, see [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=894897) post. And it turns out that there is a 64-bit version of the library in the SDK in the folder `Lib/x64`. So we must rerun the `Makefile.PL` with the correct library path:

```
perl Makefile.PL INC=-IC:/Users/Me/Libraries/npcap/Include "LIBS=-LC:/Users/Me/Libraries/npcap/Lib/x64 -lwpcap"
```

(change the paths in the above command to comply with your installation directory for the SDK) and then rerun `gmake`.

Comment: Thanks , now when i run perl Makefile it finished with success , but when i run gmake i get the below error : 
 PCAP_API char *pcap_lookupdev(char *)
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Pcap.c: In function 'XS_Net__Pcap_strerror':
Pcap.c:1703:9: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  RETVAL = pcap_strerror(error);
         ^
Pcap.xs: In function 'XS_Net__Pcap_getevent':
Pcap.xs:1038:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
         h = (unsigned int) pcap_getevent(p);
             ^

Comment: Yes I also get errors when I run `gmake`, maybe you should report it as a bug at the GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/maddingue/Net-Pcap/issues)?

Comment: See also [this blog](https://neil.tappsville.com/index.php/Perl#Net::PCAP_.3D) for a previous attempt (that seemed to work with `dmake`)

Comment: Another idea is to try install using `cygwin` ?

Comment: I was able to compile it now, see my updated answer!

Comment: Thanks I was able to compile it based on your answer ! ,now let's see how it working under windows 10 :)